# Android content provider sqlite bitwise operation selection

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I do bitwise operation in sqlite selection in Android content provider?

I created a cursor loader to load data from database, but no result return. The returning cursor's counts is zero.

```
new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Person.PERSON_CONTENT_URI,
            Person.FULL_PROJECTION,
            "( " + Person.FLAG + " & 2 ) = ?",
            new String[]{
                    String.valueOf(2)
            },
            Person.USER_NAME + " asc");
```

`sqlite` do support bitwise selection operation. Here is an example tested in PC commandline.

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table person(name text, flag integer);
sqlite> insert into person values('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 4), ('d', 8);
sqlite> select * from person where (flag & 4) == 4;
c|4
```

Why the implementation in Android doesn't support it?

How can I perform bitwise operation in sqlite selection clause in Android?

Comment: You're treating the equals' right-hand operand as text. Pass `null` for the selection args, and replace the `?` in the selection with `2`

Answer (score 0):

It's a pitfall in Android API.

As @Mike's comments, the integer selection argument must quoted in `where` string, can not pass as a text argument.

```
new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Person.PERSON_CONTENT_URI,
        Person.FULL_PROJECTION,
        "( " + Person.FLAG + " & 2 ) = 2",
        null,
        Person.USER_NAME + " asc");
```

Thanks, this save my day.